# "Pipe" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción, verbos, informática

In the context of programming, we refer to "pipe" as the action where you send the output of a process into another one.

For example, I can say:

```
echo "hello" | sed 's/h/XX/g'
#            ^
#      this is a pipe!
```

Here, the pipe `|` represents that for a given input "hello" that gets printed by the executable `echo`, another command `sed` will perform an action (replacing all `h`s with `XX`, but this is not important).

Pipe can be a noun or a verb. So what I want to know is how to say this as a verb in Spanish.

[WordReference suggests](http://www.wordreference.com/es/translation.asp?tranword=pipe) these verbs:

- canalizar
- verter

and these nouns:

- tubería
- manguera

But they are liquid-related, so I wonder if any other verb can match better in the IT context.

Comment: En el contexto informático todos sabemos que ese símbolo de barra vertical se llama _pipe_. El que no esté familiarizado con ese nombre igual no va a entender aunque se lo traduzcas como tubería o encadenamiento como sugieren las respuestas. Ese tipo de cosas es mejor ponerlas en letra itálica con su nombre original en inglés.

Comment: @DiGaleano: Con mis escasos conocimientos de informática, desconocía que esa barra vertical se llamara *pipe*. Una traducción como "encadenamiento" junto con un pequeño comentario aclaratorio la primeravez que se introduce el término lo dejaría meridianamente claro.

Comment: De acuerdo a Wikipedia (https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pleca) el caracter se llama pleca o barra vertical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

En general, en informática/computación, los términos técnicos varían de un país a otro, y lo que en un país suena natural, en otros suena forzado **o incluso mal**. Este tipo de neologismos no llegan de manera centralizada al mundo hispanohablante, y por lo mismo, unas traducciones prevalecen sobre otras en cada lugar, dependiendo de la cultura, modas, oportunidades, etc. Tómese como ejemplo el mismo *computer*, que en unos países es *ordenador* (m), en otros *computadora* (f) y en otros *computador* (m), o el *mouse*, que puede ser *ratón* (m) o simplemente *mouse* (m, con pronunciación aproximada al original inglés).

Propongo una respuesta wiki por países, para que cada uno llene con el uso de su país.

**Posibles traducciones de la acción *to pipe* (y de su efecto):**

> Encadenar (encadenado a/con)

España

> Concatenar (concatenado a/con)

Chile

> Conectar (conectado a/con)

(none yet)

**Posibles traducciones para el caracter `|` (*pipe*):**

> Tubería (f)

España

> *Pipe* (m, anglicismo no traducido)

Chile

> Barra vertical (f)
>
> Cauce (m)

Answer (score 3):

[Tubería](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tuber%C3%ADa_%28inform%C3%A1tica%29)

Pero si hay varios comandos juntos usaría *encadenar* (o *cadena de comandos*), como la [traducción portuguesa de Pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_%28Unix%29) > *Encadeamento*.

Comment: ¡Gracias! Nótese que puedes añadir un enlace seleccionando el texto y apretando Ctrl + L. De esta forma los enlaces quedan en la parte baja del texto, lo que permite una mayor claridad.

Answer (score 2):

In my opinion, in an IT context, a good translation for pipe as a verb would be

[conectar](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=conectar)

which means to connect

Comment: También **conducto** o **conexión**.

Answer (score 1):

I think that the best translation for the verb would be, as AlexBcn suggests,
[encadenar](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=encadenar)

> vtr (enlazar palabras) chain, link vtr
> make a chain of v expr
> string [sth] together v expr

or
[concatenar](http://www.wordreference.com/es/en/translation.asp?spen=concatenar)

> link vtr
> link [sth] together, put [sth] together vtr
> (formal) concatenate

as both convey the idea of "sequentially linking" of pipe

Comment: concatenar suele tener un significado diferente en el ámbito informático (concatenar dos cadenas como `$completo = $nombres . " " . $apellidos` quiere decir producir una nueva cadena con la combinación). Con `|`, en el contexto de la pregunta, se usa la salida de una operación como la entrada de una segunda operación.

Comment: Como ingeniero informático puedo decir que, al menos en mi entorno (Chile), a falta de un término propio, y para no describir la acción completa, el verbo _concatenar_ se usa sin ambigüedad

Answer (score -2):

La traducción de *pipe* en español existe, y es "**pipa**".
Es un tonel o recipiente, y para eso sirve en informática, como un recipiente de un comando, caracteres... etc.

Comment: En este caso, yo creo que el significado de *pipe* es más bien *tubería*; sirve para mandar el resultado de un comando al elemento siguiente, igual que una tubería lleva líquido de un sitio a otro.

Comment: Coincido con @Gorpik, la definición que se aplica para describir el concepto de encadenar comandos, pasando el resultado de un comando al siguiente está más relacionado con "a tube used to convey water, gas, oil, or other fluid substances", es decir, un tubo o tubería por el que fluye algo, no es un tonel ni un recipiente.