# Palabras con diferencia de género según la región

Tags: diferencias-regionales, género

El Diccionario de la Lengua recoge en [**pollero, ra**](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Tau7jdO) dos acepciones casi idénticas:

> 2. m. y f. *Méx*. Persona que transporta trabajadores indocumentados a los Estados Unidos de América.
>   4. m. *El Salv*. Hombre que transporta trabajadores indocumentados a los Estados Unidos de América.

Las únicas diferencias que percibo son, aparte de la zona (México o El Salvador) en el género: en México es *masculino y femenino*, y por tanto "**Persona** que ...", mientras que en El Salvador es exclusivamente *masculino* y, por tanto, "**Hombre** que ..."

¿Hay otras palabras que, describiendo lo mismo, tengan una diferencia análoga de género según la región?

Answer (score 5):

Pues mira, una que acabo de descubrir hace poco: **[pijama](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SyKQl6b)** es una palabra masculina [en algunas regiones](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=pijama), como España y el cono sur de América, mientras que en el resto de regiones se usa como femenino.

También es cierto que en algunas regiones cambia su pronunciación por "piyama", pero no sé si estas regiones coinciden con las de su uso en femenino.

Comment: Hay alguna más, se me ocurren _calor_ y _sartén_. Lo curioso de la pregunta es que la palabra tiene los dos géneros diferenciados con la terminación **-a** y **-o** pero en una zona específica parece que solo se usa el masculino

Comment: @blonfu cierto, la de "sartén" la aprendí viendo La Sirenita ("nadie nos fríe ni nos cocina en un sartén"). Y la de "calor", bueno, aquí en Andalucía (España) la usamos con todos los géneros y números posibles (_el caló, la caló, loh caloreh y lah caloreh_).

Answer (score 5):

## Palabras ambiguas

Los otros comentarios se refieren a palabras *ambiguas*, i.e. palabras que tienen un género distinto en distintos dialectos/contextos etc pero no cambian definición.

Ejemplos incluyen:

- el/la [arte](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3q9w3lk), [azúcar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4gcuzQk), [mar](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OLDn0QL), [duermevela](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EEztonx) , [Internet](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LvskgUG), [interrogante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=LwoV9X4), [linde](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NMVIm96), [mimbre](http://dle.rae.es/?id=PGv9IZg), [pelambre](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SMrGCJh), [prez](http://dle.rae.es/?id=U9uBWIv), [pringue](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UCLqZdA), [radio](http://dle.rae.es/?id=V1J0Z3h), [testuz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZfrCtKU), [tizne](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZuJm4Dd), [bermuda(s)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5NzSlV3)

---

- [el color](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9qYXXhD) `Usado también como femenino`
- [el/la reuma](http://dle.rae.es/?id=WLxWZbl) `Usado más en masculino` (también *reúma*)
- [el/la trípode](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ahY832G) `Usado más en masculino`
- [el/la autoclave](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4RWItK6) `usado menos como femenino`
- [el/la cutis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BmxbqSX) `Usado menos como femenino`
- [contraluz](http://dle.rae.es/?id=AaD4OLA), [faira](http://dle.rae.es/?id=HchsbQt), [maratón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=OM6EdRu), [arrelde](http://dle.rae.es/?id=3iTPBox), [lis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NPcHkkW), [demo](http://dle.rae.es/?id=C9L4usv), [coriza](http://dle.rae.es/?id=At2rpaY), [tanka](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Z5TPCjW)

---

- [el/la babel](http://dle.rae.es/?id=4iQ8cYD) `Usado más en femenino`
- [el/la dotis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=EAgN6Fq) `Usado más en femenino`
- [el/la lente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=N7o6jFG) `Usado más en femenino`
- [el/la tortícolis](http://dle.rae.es/?id=a8PcE5N) `Usado menos como masculino` (también *torticolis*)

---

#### Históricamente

- [la esfinge](http://dle.rae.es/?id=GPVg5OI) `Era usado también como masculino`
- [la llama](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NTIHQa3) `Era usado también como masculino`
- [la tilde](http://dle.rae.es/?id=ZkHNOE8) `Era usado también como masculino`
- [la várice](http://dle.rae.es/?id=bNpNyyP) `Era usado también como masculino`
- [la hipérbola](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KQeGz9i) `Era usado también como masculino`
- [el anatema](http://dle.rae.es/?id=2Wonp5z) `Era usado también como femenino`
- [el cisma](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9Lbbywe) `Era usado también como femenino`
- [el desorden](http://dle.rae.es/?id=DF5Xi1F) `Era usado también como femenino`
- [el fénix](http://dle.rae.es/?id=Hky61us) `Era usado también como femenino`
- [el herpes](http://dle.rae.es/?id=KEWLXVi) `Era usado también como femenino`
- [el puente](http://dle.rae.es/?id=UZtOEos) `Era usado también como femenino` `Dialectalmente, usado como femenino`
- [el almicantarat](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1ymY0Yl) `Era usado también como femenino`

---

#### Regionalmente

- [la crin](http://dle.rae.es/?id=BGrSZka) `En algunos lugares de España y América, usado también como masculino`
- [la sartén](http://dle.rae.es/?id=XKCB8YU) `En muchos lugares de América y España, usado como masculino`
- [las saludes](http://dle.rae.es/?id=X7YZCmm) `En Ecuador, usado también como masculino plural`
- [la bossa nova](http://dle.rae.es/?id=5xWVImL#RKCKxhw) `En Bolivia, Chile y Nicaragua, usado también como masculino`
- [el calor](http://dle.rae.es/?id=6qw2prQ) `En Andalucía y algunos lugares de América, usado también como femenino`
- [el pijama](http://dle.rae.es/?id=SyKQl6b) `En algunos lugares de América, usado también como femenino`
- [el caparazón](http://dle.rae.es/?id=7HsQd4w) `En algunos lugares de América, usado como femenino`

---

y hay unos que a veces se tratan como masculino/femenino, en algunos dialectos, pero prescriptivamente son de *un* género:

- [la libido](http://dle.rae.es/?id=NEw80OX) ([ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=el+libido%2C+la+libido&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21)), [la web](http://dle.rae.es/?id=c6FIuv9) ([ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=el+web%2C+la+web&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21)), [el enema](http://dle.rae.es/?id=FFmEYg5|FFpozdY) ([ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=el+enema%2C+la+enema&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21)), [el treponema](http://dle.rae.es/?id=aawyhzX), [el yoga](http://dle.rae.es/?id=cCWOUIz) ([ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=el+yoga%2C+la+yoga&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=21))

---

## Profesiones y género

Pero el ejemplo que das tú es de una palabra que refiere a una *persona*, que puede referir/declinar para los dos géneros en algunos dialectos, pero en otros refiere exclusivamente a uno.

La mayoría de esas palabras son profesiones que históricamente hacían solo los hombres.

Aquí hay unos ejemplos:

- el jefe, la jefa [/ la jefe](http://dle.rae.es/?id=MPAoQ4z) — [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+jefe%2C+la+jefa&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=21)
- el presidente, la presidenta [(/ la presidente)](http://dle.rae.es/?id=U6Yu3bh) — [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+presidente%2C+la+presidenta&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=21)
- el almirante, la almiranta [/ la almirante](http://dle.rae.es/?id=1z4MnwR) — [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+almirante%2C+la+almiranta&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=21)
- el poeta, la poetisa [/ la poeta](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TUUD7eg) — [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+poeta%2C+la+poetisa&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=21)
- el ingeniero, la ingeniera / la ingeniero — [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+ingeniero%2Cla+ingeniera&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=21)
- el medico, la medica / la medico
- el bebé, [la bebé / la beba](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/?key=beb%C3%A9)<sup>1</sup> — [ngrams](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=la+beb%C3%A9_NOUN%2Cla+beba_NOUN&year_start=1600&year_end=2000&corpus=21)

---

**Notas:**

1.

> **bebé o bebe**
>
> <sup>1. *‘Niño pequeño, especialmente el que aún mama’*. Procede del francés, lo que explica la acentuación aguda de *bebé*, única forma que se usa en España. En algunas zonas de América, especialmente en el Cono Sur, se usa más la forma llana *bebe* `[bébe]`.</sup>
>
> <sup>2. En España, bebé funciona generalmente como [sustantivo epiceno masculino](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg#1b):</sup>
>
> > <sup>«*En la mochila de Carolina apareció un bebé muerto. La niña era de Carolina*» (*Mundo* [Esp.] 20.11.96);</sup>
>
> <sup>en América, salvo en los países del [Río de la Plata](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=beb%E9#3), tanto la forma aguda como la llana se usan a menudo como [sustantivos comunes en cuanto al género](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=Tr5x8MFOuD6DVTlDBg#1a):</sup>
>
> > <sup>«*Dijo que la bebé estaba viva*» (*Tiempo* [Col.] 16.11.94);</sup>
> >     <sup>«*Tanto la madre como la bebe fueron trasladadas al hospital*» (*DAméricas* [EE. UU.] 14.4.97).</sup>
>
> <sup>3. En el Río de la Plata, la forma llana se usa normalmente con dos terminaciones (*el bebe, la beba*):</sup>
>
> > <sup>«*Franco sacó a la beba de su camita*» (*Abc* [Par.] 19.12.96).</sup>

---

#### Fuentes

<sup>• https://www.thoughtco.com/sometimes-masculine-sometimes-feminine-3079259</sup>

Comment: Muy completa respuesta! Sólo agregaría el ejemplo computador (Chile y creo que Colombia)/computadora (resto de Latinoamérica, si no me equivoco). Esta palabra ha dado pie a varias preguntas de diferencias regionales

Comment: En [esta pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/25781/existe-alg%c3%ban-t%c3%a9rmino-para-ordenador-y-computadora-que-se-entienda-en-todos) fedorqui pregunta con maestría sobre esta palabra. Y en [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/16872/pipe-in-spanish/16892#16892) a una pregunta distinta sugiero una aparente causa