# ¿Por qué se decía "la color" en el siglo XVII? ¿Por qué cambió a "el color"?

Tags: historia, sustantivos, género, colores

Acabo de leer el siguiente texto:

> *No las tuvo todas consigo don Quijote, que también se estremeció y encogió de hombros y perdió la color del rostro.*
>
> Miguel de Cervantes Saavedra, "Segunda parte del ingenioso caballero don Quijote de la Mancha", 1615 (España).

Me llamó la atención lo de "la color", y leo en el diccionario de Covarrubias (1611) que por la época al parecer se decía así:

> Vnas de las colores son naturales, otras artificiales, y algunas compuestas, mezclando vnas con otras; dedõde resulta vna tercera color [...].

Sin embargo, un siglo más tarde encuentro esto en el Diccionario de Autoridades:

> COLOR. s. m. El objeto proprio y formal de la vista. El colór negro y el blanco son los extremos de los colores. Unos son naturales, otros artificiales, y algúnos compuestos, mezclando unos con otros, de donde resulta un tercero color [...].

La RAE fusilando a Covarrubias. Añade después:

> Aunque lo mas proprio y conforme à su origen, es usar este nombre como masculino, algúnos le usan como femenino.

Sí, algunos como Cervantes y Covarrubias. Si según su origen debió ser masculino, ¿por qué se usaba como femenino entre los siglos XV y XVII? ¿Fue la RAE quien con su diccionario ayudó a que se asentara su uso en masculino?

Comment: interesante... sera un caso similar a "la calor" ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Incluso ahora, *color* (especialmente cuando se usa para describir el color de la superficie del rostro humano) se puede tomar cualquiera género:

> #### [color](http://dle.rae.es/?id=9qYXXhD)
>
> `Del lat. color, -ōris.`
>
> 1. m. Sensación producida por los rayos luminosos que impresionan los órganos visuales y que depende de la longitud de onda. **U. t. c. f.**
> 2. m. color natural de la tez humana. **U. t. c. f.**

Pero como dice el DPD, puede parecer arcaico usar el femenino:

> #### [color](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?key=color)
>
> **1.** Cuando significa ‘cualidad de los seres por la cual impresionan la retina de modo diferente según cómo reflejen los rayos luminosos’ y ‘cada uno de los distintos modos en que puede percibirse esta cualidad’, **es masculino en la lengua general culta:**
>
> > *«En otoño, las arboledas van perdiendo el color verde»* (*Merino Orilla* [Esp. 1985]).
>
> **Su uso en femenino, normal en el español medieval y clásico, es ajeno hoy a la norma culta y debe evitarse.** El femenino puede aparecer también en textos literarios, con finalidad arcaizante. Sí es normal su empleo en femenino, en países como Chile o el Ecuador, para designar cierto colorante alimentario:
>
> > *«Se fríe la cebolla con la color, y se añade a las lentejas»* (*Huneeus Cocina* [Chile 1989]).

La palabra *color* sí es masculino en latín, pero en las lenguas romances actuales, su género es una mezcla de femenino y masculino:

- `Old Portuguese` color, coor *f.* → `Portuguese` cor *f.* | `Galician` cor *f.*
- `Asturian` color, collor *m.*
- `Aragonese` color *f.*
- `Old Occitan` color *f.* → `Catalan` color *f., m.* | `Occitan` color *f.*
- `Old French` color, colour, colur, culur *f.* → `French` couleur *f.*
- `Italian` color, colore *m.*
- `Dalmatian` colaur, kolaur *m.*

Creo que es por la influencia de las lenguas vecinas que en castellano puede tomar cualquier género.

Según la [*Nueva gramática de la lengua española*](http://www.rae.es/sites/default/files/Sala_prensa_Dosier_Gramatica_2009.pdf) (2009, **11.7g**), todavía en Andalucía y algunas otras áreas se usa *la color* en la lengua popular ocasionalmente:

> Los factores que determinan la variación pueden ser históricos o geográficos. Los sustantivos *análisis, énfasis* y otros similares de origen griego eran mayoritariamente femeninos hasta el siglo XIX; **también lo eran *color*** y *puente* en la lengua medieval y clásica. ***Color* se usa todavía ocasionalmente como femenino en la lengua popular de Andalucía (España) y en algunas otras áreas hispanohablantes, pero no en los registros formales;**

En [esta respuesta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/a/23660/18348) hay más ejemplos de palabras que son válidas con ambos géneros.

Comment: 34 casos me ha encontrado el CREA de "la color" en documentos recientes, no lo habría imaginado.