# ¿Qué nombre recibe en español el signo ✓?

Tags: solicitud-de-término

Buscando en el traductor de Google la traducción al inglés de "paloma", me encuentro con que me suelta la siguiente definición:

> Señal que se pone en un escrito para indicar un acierto o una aprobación, y que consiste en una raya diagonal con una leve inflexión.

Debo reconocer que no era esa precisamente la definición que me esperaba, aunque luego buscando en el *Diccionario de americanismos* me di cuenta de que es [la forma que se llama a la marca ✓ en México](http://lema.rae.es/damer/?key=paloma).

Dado que es un término localizado en un país concreto y no de uso extendido en los países de habla hispana, ¿cuál es el nombre oficial de este signo en español?

Comment: Por si reconoces, como yo, cierta falta de imaginación en las formas españolas, tal vez te gustaría saber que en danés este símbolo se llama normalmente ‘pata de mosca’ (_flueben_), lo que me parece un poco más imaginativo.

Comment: Yo siempre lo he conocido como "chulo" o "chulito" :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

En el apéndice [Símbolos o signos no alfabetizables](http://www.rae.es/diccionario-panhispanico-de-dudas/apendices/simbolos-o-signos-no-alfabetizables), la RAE señala:

> En esta lista se recogen los símbolos no alfabetizables más usuales.
>
> **✓** → **verificación**

Dado que no tiene ninguna nota sobre ámbito geográfico limitado, podemos asumir que es válido en todos los países de habla hispana (*ergo cada uno de nosotros puede decir "✓, lo conozco"*).

---

Como curiosidad, en el [chat de Stack Overflow en español](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol) una vez [hicimos entre todos](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/36861186#36861186) un JSON con unas cuantas variantes sacadas de distintos países: Argentina, España, Chile...

He aquí la última versión:

```
{
    "no se trabaja": ["feriado", "fiesta", "festivo", "no laborable", "no hábil"],
    "✔️": ["tilde", "marca de verificación", "marca de aceptación", "visto", "verificado",
           "marca de cotejo", "chequeado", "comprobado", "hecho", "señal de cotejo", "marca de comprobación",
           "revisado", "paloma", "gaviota", "chulo", "tick", "check"],
    "#": ["numeral", "almohadilla", "gato", "celdilla", "signo de número",
           "michi", "la del tres en raya", "cuadradillo", "ta-te-ti",
           "sostenido", "ancla", "hashtag", "sharp", "hash",
           "cardinal"],
    "bueno": ["copado", "chido", "chévere", "guay", "padre", "bacán", "suave", "bárbaro", "chilo", "chivo", "fetén", "fino"]
}
```

Comment: Con la página de símbolos o signos no alfabetizables he aprendido además una palabra nueva: _[pleca](http://dle.rae.es/?id=TOFKW9u)_ es como se llama a la barra vertical (|). El conjunto || que se usa a veces para separar definiciones en el diccionario se denomina _doble pleca_.

Comment: @CarlosAlejo interesante esta. En su momento pregunté por el [_pipe_ como verbo](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/16872/1674). Ah, en catalán tenemos una palabra que suena casi igual: [_cleca_](http://www.diccionari.cat/lexicx.jsp?GECART=0030622)... lo que pasa es que quiere decir bofetada :)

Answer (score 7):

No tiene traducción oficial, aunque se suele conocer como "visto" o "visto bueno".

La Fundéu BBVA, entre otras cosas, por lo ambiguo y confuso que resulta lo de "visto",  propuso en su momento traducirlo como "Tic" o "Marca". referencia: [Tic o marca, dos alternativas a check](http://www.fundeu.es/recomendacion/tic-o-marca-dos-alternativas-a-check/)

Answer (score 2):

Así es, se le conoce como **paloma** en la mayoria de los casos, y tambien como otros comentaron, se le puede llamar **tic** o **visto** dependiendo del contexto.

Por ejemplo, cuando es para calificar un examen se le llama palomita.

Tambien se le puede llamar visto o tic cuando se trata de marcar una lista.

Comment: Yo conozco este símbolo como *palomita.*