# ¿Por qué se le dice "palomita" al símbolo de verificación?

Tags: uso-de-palabras, méxico, terminología, símbolos

Ya se ha preguntado antes [cuál es el nombre del símbolo de "✓"](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21048/5481).
Pero ¿alguien sabe cómo fue que adquirió el nombre "palomita"?

Comment: Le adicioné la etiqueta México porque se que ellos le dicen así. En Colombia le decimos "chulo"

Answer (score 5):

Casi con toda seguridad, por la similitud que tiene con el trazo que se suele usar para representar un ave o pájaro en dibujos simples. Ejemplo:

[image: fuente: https://practicarte.com/blog/dibujos-faciles-a-lapiz/]

Pero cabe recordar que ["palomita" no es el nombre más usado](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/21048/13628).

Comment: para mi que eso que has dibujado son más bien gaviotas XD